# How to create an account from a Spring MVC project

Tags: remix, ethereumj, java

I am working on Ethereum blockchian.
I have create a login page using Spring MVC 4 and it is connected to MySQL DB.
Now I want to assign coinbase to the successful registration of the user.

*My Idea* :: user is directed to register page(Spring-jsp) where he fills all details in the field `(name, email_id,contact,country,PASSWORD,CONFIRM PASSWORD)` , when user clicks on "create user"(register) method like `web3.eth.personal.newAccount(PASSWORD)` should be invoked and geth should create a coinbase for this particular user registration.

When I get the coinbase generated for this particular registration I'll map it in DB for next user login.

How to tackle this solution using Spring MVC 4.
Source code is a big welcome.
I have not started implementing it yet, just have setup the application that registers user and holds the details with password in db and for next login it checks for password and username match in database successful login vl take to a Form.